# Jmeter cyclic running tests

Tags: testing, jmeter, automated-tests

I want to run cyclical tests in jmeter. I want them to run every day and than run for 10 minutes (every day for 10 minutes). How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For running test for 10 minutes there are following options:

   - In the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) tick "Specify Thead lifetime" and put `600` into "Duration" field:

     [image]
   - Or use [Runtime Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Runtime_Controller) which allows setting how long its children are allowed to run

     [image]
2. With regards to running the test every day, you can go for:

   - [Windows Task Scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler)
   - Linux/Unix [crontab](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html)
   - MacOS [launchd](https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-use-launchd-to-run-services-in-macos-b972ed1e352)
   - or you can put the JMeter job under the orchestration of a [Continuous Integration](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jenkins-vs-other-open-source-continuous-integration-servers/) server, any of them can run specified job on the schedule or basing on various different triggers, tracks job status (successful or failed), some of them provide performance trends

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to answer your (a bit too broad) question.
Here are some insights that could help:

- to launch a JMeter test that last 10 minutes, you have to configure a job in JMeter with such a duration. Then you have to lear how to launch it via command line instead of via the graphical interface (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24549907/1826804) for example)
- to launch your JMeter test every day, you can use a Continuous Integration tool like [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/). In this tool, you will be able to create some jobs with a specific schedule (every day in your case) and a specific task (launch my JMeter test via command line)